# GPars Process the huge list doing the fix size parallelisation on its portions

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, gpars

I'm looking for the GPars functionality which allows to separate the big task in sequencially executed portions of parallized subtasks sets.

i.e. iterating the Array size of **K**, doing the sequencial assignments of parallel tasks blocks each having the size of  **threadCount**.

In other words do not iterate the array at the first and submit all tasks at once, but doing the assignment sequencially, using i.e. pagination, when the previous block is ready (preventing OOM).

Something like the code below, but instead of listing pages and submitting tasks at first, the pages has to be processed sequencialy.

`myHugeList.getNextPage().each {
    withPool(threadCount) { Closure.callAsync().get() }
}`

Thanks,
Yefym

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for something along these lines:

withPool(numOfThreads) {
    for(entriesInPage in myHugeList.splitIntoPages) {
        resultPages << entriesInPage.collectParallel(myClosure)
    }
}
The downside is that each iteration waits for the previous one to complete, potentially leaving some of the threads underutilized.

One of the alternatives could be a group of actors pulling tasks from a dispatcher, which manages myHugeList.